# Java Generic Interface Return Type

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, interface

Migrating to Java from C++.

I have a third party code with an interface I am required to implement which goes something like this.

```
public interface Foo<T>{
       public T doSomething();
}
```

I want to implement this interface so that I can call doSomething() and get 3 different classes `A, B and C` which extend a common base `Z` as below.

```
public class A extends Z{...};
public class B extends Z{...};
public class C extends Z{...};
```

I could not find any way of avoiding writing the following 3 classes.

```
public class ARet implements Foo<A>{...}
public class BRet implements Foo<B>{...}
public class CRet implements Foo<C>{...}
```

For the given interface `Foo`, is it not possible to write an implementation which returns `T extends Z` something which would look like `public class Ret implements Foo<T extends Z>{...}`. This does not appear to work. Is there any way of avoiding the 3 classes or there is no way around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the implementation of the interface to be generic, you need to declare T as a generic type parameter of Ret :

```
public class Ret<T extends Z> implements Foo<T>{...}
```

Comment: Note the function signature `T doSomething()` in the interface. It will return a type `T` without ever taking a `T` object as one of the parameter. This implies that the object `T` which is to be returned has to be created in the function `doSomething()`. While I am new to Java,  my understanding was that this was not possible due to type erasure. Or have I misunderstood the concepts?

Comment: @cplusplusrat It can also mean that the implementing class has a `set(T object)` or some other method that passes a `T` instance to an instance of the implementing class, and your `something()` method returns that instance. This would be similar to the `java.util.List<T>` interface, whose `get(int i)` method returns a `T` instance. The `T` instance cannot be created in the `doSomething()` method, unless you pass a `Class<T>` argument to it.

Comment: Alright, so for your solution to work, there is no escaping the setter method so that  `doSomething()` has the object to work on and return. Thats what I thought, but needed a second opinion. Thanks. I will mark this as resolved.